# Doing a Binary Search on a List and returning using Lookup

Tags: c#, .net, linq, search, collections

Hi I have a binary search method to search for a particular record. I would have an index location. Now i want to use this index location to fetch from the recordlist as group by using lookup and not Groupby:

```
    public static Data BinSearch(MyData searchDate)
        {
            IComparer<Data> rc = new RecComparer();

            int index;
            index = recordList.BinarySearch(searchDate, (IComparer<MyData>)rc);
            Console.WriteLine(index);
             int i = 1;
            foreach (var r in recordList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Line:" + i + " " + r.DateDetails + " " + r.TrackDetails);
                i++;
            }  
            if (index >= 0)
            {
               // return recordList[index];
            }

            index = ~index;

            if (index == 0 || index == recordList.Count)
            {
              //  return null;
            }

            int newIndex = (((index-1)+index)/2)+1;
            string pointer = recordList[newIndex].DateDetails;
```

My pointer comes out correctly. and points to the right index I need. Now using the below line of code I'm getting into groups by using lookup:

```
 var lookup = recordList.ToLookup(d => d.DateDetails);
```

Now is where the problem comes up if I write the following code:

```
    var test = lookup.ElementAt(pointer);
     foreach (var print in lookup.ElementAt(newIndex))
           {Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", print.Data1, print.Data2);
return (print);


 }
}
```

It's giving me an exception outOF range because initially the recordlist had 180+ records in the recordlist. Now with lookup it did a grouping and it became around 60 records in the test variable. So it's throwing an exception.

I hope you understood my problem.How do I get the last part to work, because I want to return as a Data type with lookup and not Igrouping type by groupby.

Please help. THank you

Comment: If you want to access the elements by index, it is just unreasonable to use a lookup. Just use the original list.

Comment: Yes, I need to access the elements by index but at the same time i need a grouping of those. My aim here is to do a binary search which return an index (int), then take this element(index) and create a group out of it with lookup. so I can return this group with type of data. Because this element it matches will not be a single element there can be four or 5 elements with the same match starting from this index.

Comment: Then a lookup is a bit too much. Why not just `.Where(e => e.data = searchData)`? I guess the binary search is used to speed things up (if your data is sorted). Then you could manually select the matching elements in the surrounding of the found element per `yield return`. Creating a lookup is definitely way slower than a simple `Where`.

Comment: Okay I did this :    var lookup = recordList.Where(e => e.Data1 = pointer); . Pointer here is the data at newIndex I want to look for and group the next 3-4 records matching this criteria. It's giving me an error Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool